# Se generan muchos archivos en la carpeta temporal de Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, aws

Uno de nuestros clientes nos informo que la aplicación que hicimos para ellos y que esta hosteada en AWS se caia constantemente. Nos pusimos a revisar los logs y descubrimos que el servidor se caia y arrojaba la siguiente excepcion:

"too many open files"

Entonces subimos el limite de archivos permitidos por el servidor y pusimos a monitorear cuantos archivos abria la aplicacion. Durante 2 dias el numero no paro de incrementar y decidimos averiguar que archivos estaban siendo utilizados por el proceso de Java. Despues de una larga investigacion descartamos que el problema sean conexiones de la base que no se cerraban y descubrimos que en la carpeta "/opt/tomcat/temp" se estan creando de manera infinita archivos temporales con 0 de tamaño pero que la aplicacion por algun motivo los mantiene abiertos.

Ejemplos de estos archivos son los siguientes:

oew974702517498114636.hop
oew975038640901567654.hop
oew975419048649710675.hop
oew976498632463201934.hop
oew97661135001107305.hop
oew97786752219273069.hop
oew978096979722662729.hop
oew979934500917317891.hop
oew980223348673981682.hop
oew980401664060722912.hop
oew982077290584656345.hop
oew982911046120251661.hop
oew984241948479464632.hop
oew984817715497603618.hop
oew987522880029695756.hop
oew989321970952129224.hop

Y de ese tipo hay aldrededor de 7000 y siguen subiendo.

¿Cual podria ser el problema? ¿ Por que se generan estos archivos? ¿ Como se podria solucionar el problema y evitar que se creen tantos archivos?

Comment: Lo único que puedo encontrar es [esto](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/issues/65). Parece que estás usando un framework que lleva abandonado desde hace años... y tiene algún bug ahí. Al menos es código abierto y podríais buscar una solución

Comment: Gracias a tu comentario pude encontrar el error en cuestion. La libreria que estaba usando generaba archivos temporales los cuales mantenia abiertos llegando a dar una excepcion del tipo "too many open files". Mi solucion fue crear un thread que se ejecuta cada 30 min y elimina los archivos con esta extension. No es la solucion mas elegante pero da resultado.

Comment: No es lo más elegante pero si funciona... me alegro de haberte ayudado, aunque sea un poco.